# JQuery bind on ajax HTML and get class instance value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the Jquery's load method to return results based on the user's input:

```
$('#textbox').bind('input propertychange', function() {
        $('#textbox').load('searchurl/'+$("#textbox").val() );
});
```

I need my loaded content to still respond to clicks so I use this code:

```
$(document).on("click", '.lightbox', function(event) { 
        //do some stuff
});
```

At this point everything is going good.  However I would like to get an attribute from my .lightbox class.  this.attr will reference the document not the .lightbox class that was clicked.  How do I reference .lightbox attributes?

Comment: ``$(this),attr()`` will get the clicked element attribute

Comment: Ah.  I figured it was simple.  Just couldn't the right combo on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ehsan already said in the comments, `$(this).attr()` will do what you want. I made a small [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7wnn7/):

```
<input type="button" value="click me" class="lightbox" id="attr1">
<input type="button" value="click me" class="lightbox" id="attr2">
<input type="button" value="click me" class="lightbox" id="attr3">

$(document).on("click", '.lightbox', function(event) { 
        alert($(this).attr("id"))
});
```